# Private Storage Cloud

Tags: 12.04, cloud, storage, open-source, openstack

I'm absolute new to this area. So, please be gentle :-)

I'm looking at the possibility for my company to start a private storage cloud using cheap hardware and software. For example, SATA storage boxes, Assembled servers, and open source and free software. Our company is into very specific business with particular set of clients. We want to offer them the possibility of digital archiving of their files and other information.

Where do I need to start to setup a pilot setup to show the strength of cloud compared to direct access to storage over the internet. I'm expecting to show automatic sizing, redundancy, virtualization, security, accessibility etc.

Please guide me to a starting point.

Comment: Am I right thinking you want to use Ubuntu for this setup? Because this is a Ubuntu Question-Answer site...

Comment: Thank you Eliah, I will be using Ubuntu. I've previous experience in Solaris and Linux. That was few years back though. I've seen Ubuntu and OpenStack documentation. However, as I mentioned, I'm trying to make sense of the 'concept' first before I do the hands on.

Comment: Hi Indian, feel free to read the FAQ. Your questions should be specific enough for an answer to be possible. Can you narrow it down?

Comment: I'm terribly sorry for wasting your time. To be specific, I would like to know the minimum hardware, software and tools necessary to setup a pilot cloud project. Also, if you know any specific forums or websites that are dedicated to helping in building private clouds using Open source and free software tools

Answer (score -1):

Using OpenStack? Check out ZeroStack!They make building a private cloud easy and expose a 100% pure OpenStack API! http://www.zerostack.com/